# Android SingleTask, SingleTop and Home Button

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

In my application there is a behavior that I don't understand. I have the `MainActivity` A as `SingleTask`.
It calls an `Activity` B that is `SingleTask` too.
When I press the `Home` button in the second activity to open another application, and after that I try to go to my application mantaining `Home` button pressed i always go to Main `Activity`, and I want second activity to be opened mantaining the state that had when i press `Home` button.

I've tried setting then second activity to singleTop and it doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: use singleTop for your secondActivity, ity reflect same behavior as singleTask, but in same stack..

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of activity back stack becomes quit weird when define main activity with singleTask at the same time:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What even worse is there is no clear explanation in the official dev guide regarding to this special use case. Some sections related to this topic are even self-contradictory.

Try using launchMode="standard" on your `MainActivity` A, and `launchMode="singleTask"` on your `Activity` B, which will give the expect behaviour you described.

Comment: This just happened to me and your explanation helped me figure it out. For me, I had to make both the "caller task" and the destination task both have anything but singleTask or singleInstance. Once I did that, it worked. It's explained in the dev docs, but in a way that would be hard to catch even for a Computer Science major